# Parse public keys from .txt file by php

Tags: php

I have .txt file with list of public keys and its ids and status. Exists some "best practice" method how can I extract one of this public key based on KEY_ID in php from .txt file?

keys.txt

```
KEY_ID: 1
STATUS: VALID
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEaq6djyzkpHdX7kt8DsSt6IuSoXjp
WVlLfnZPoLaGKc/2BSfYQuFIO2hfgueQINJN3ZdujYXfUJ7Who+XkcJqHQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

KEY_ID: 2
STATUS: VALID
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE+Y5mYZL/EEY9zGji+hrgGkeoyccK
D0/oBoSDALHc9+LXHKsxXiEV7/h6d6+fKRDb6Wtx5cMzXT9HyY+TjPeuTg==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

KEY_ID: 3
STATUS: VALID
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEkvgJ6sc2MM0AAFUJbVOD/i34YJJ8
ineqTN+DMjpI5q7fQNPEv9y2z/ecPl8qPus8flS4iLOOxdwGoF1mU9lwfA==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: This is actually a useful question. The bank TatraBanka offers their public keys in the above format, and in order to implement their online payment system, you need to use one of the keys above. Maybe the question could have been better phrased, but I don't see the reason why it's been downvoted. It's been helpful for me because I'm dealing with the exact same situation right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$keys = file_get_contents("keys.txt");
$keyid = 2;

if(($key = getKeyById($keyid, $keys)) !== null)
    echo "<pre>".$key."</pre>";
else
    echo "not found";

function getKeyById($id, $keys){
    if(preg_match("~KEY_ID: $id\s+STATUS: VALID\s+(-{5}BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-{5}.+?-{5}END PUBLIC KEY-{5})~s", $keys, $match)){
        $result = $match[1];

        return $result;
    }
    return null;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simplified regex would involve a lookbehind:

```
(?<=VALID\n)(.*\n){3}(-----END PUBLIC KEY-----)
```

Here is an [EXAMPLE](https://regex101.com/r/eC8bY6/1). The explanation of what is occurring in the upper right hand of the interface is very valuable for understanding how the regex works.

A *positive lookbehind* (you can also use negative lookbehinds) looks for something that comes after something else. In this case you want three lines (and their newlines) after the line containing "VALID" (and its newline) plus the final line containing "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----".

How could you use this in code? You would read the entire file and then parse the keys into an array:

```
// read the file 
$keyfile = fopen("keys.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$keycontents = fread($keyfile,filesize("keys.txt"));
fclose($keyfile);

$pattern_to_match = '/(?<=VALID\n)(.*\n){3}(-----END PUBLIC KEY-----)/';

// perform the match
preg_match_all($pattern_to_match, $keycontents, $keys, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

// view the array
echo "<pre>";
print_r($keys[0]);
```

We use `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` here to make sure that `$keys[0]` is an array of full pattern matches making each array element one of the keys in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
<?php

$s = "KEY_ID: 1
STATUS: VALID
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEaq6djyzkpHdX7kt8DsSt6IuSoXjp
WVlLfnZPoLaGKc/2BSfYQuFIO2hfgueQINJN3ZdujYXfUJ7Who+XkcJqHQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

KEY_ID: 2
STATUS: VALID
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE+Y5mYZL/EEY9zGji+hrgGkeoyccK
D0/oBoSDALHc9+LXHKsxXiEV7/h6d6+fKRDb6Wtx5cMzXT9HyY+TjPeuTg==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

KEY_ID: 3
STATUS: VALID
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEkvgJ6sc2MM0AAFUJbVOD/i34YJJ8
ineqTN+DMjpI5q7fQNPEv9y2z/ecPl8qPus8flS4iLOOxdwGoF1mU9lwfA==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

preg_match_all('/KEY_ID: (\d+)\s+STATUS: VALID\s+(-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----[\s\S]+?-----END PUBLIC KEY-----)/', $s, $matches);
$id2key = array();
foreach ($matches[1] as $i => $id) {
    $key = $matches[2][$i];
    $id2key[$id] = $key;
}

print_r($id2key);
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [1] => -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEaq6djyzkpHdX7kt8DsSt6IuSoXjp
WVlLfnZPoLaGKc/2BSfYQuFIO2hfgueQINJN3ZdujYXfUJ7Who+XkcJqHQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
    [2] => -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE+Y5mYZL/EEY9zGji+hrgGkeoyccK
D0/oBoSDALHc9+LXHKsxXiEV7/h6d6+fKRDb6Wtx5cMzXT9HyY+TjPeuTg==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
    [3] => -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEkvgJ6sc2MM0AAFUJbVOD/i34YJJ8
ineqTN+DMjpI5q7fQNPEv9y2z/ecPl8qPus8flS4iLOOxdwGoF1mU9lwfA==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
)
```