# Get ECDSA key by id for openssl_verify function

Tags: php, verify, php-openssl, ecdsa

I need a little help.
I have a txt file with ecdsa public keys:

```
KEY_ID: 1
STATUS: VALID
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE+Y5mYZL/EEY9zGji+hrgGkeoyccK
D0/oBoSDALHc9+LXHKsxXiEV7/h6d6+fKRDb6Wtx5cMzXT9HyY+TjPeuTg==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

KEY_ID: 2
STATUS: VALID
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEaq6djyzkpHdX7kt8DsSt6IuSoXjp
WVlLfnZPoLaGKc/2BSfYQuFIO2hfgueQINJN3ZdujYXfUJ7Who+XkcJqHQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

KEY_ID: 3
STATUS: VALID
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEkvgJ6sc2MM0AAFUJbVOD/i34YJJ8
ineqTN+DMjpI5q7fQNPEv9y2z/ecPl8qPus8flS4iLOOxdwGoF1mU9lwfA==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Now I need use key by ID in `openssl_verify` function.

My code:

```
$ecdsa_url_string = 'ECDSA_URL_STRING';
$stringToVerify = 'MY_STRING';
$ecdsa_keys = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents(PATH . '/ecdsa_keys.txt'));

$verified = openssl_verify($stringToVerify,pack("H*",$ecdsa_url_string ),$ecdsa_keys,"sha256");

if($verified === 1){
.....
}
```

Now my question/problem:
I also have the KEY_ID parameter in the return URL. When ID is 1, everything is OK because `openssl_pkey_get_public` function always returns only the ID 1 key.

Q1: I can not retrieve the other keys.
Q2: How do I specify which ID I want use for `openssl_pkey_get_public`?

I am ashamed of my ignorance and my stupidity.
Can anyone please help me with this?
thx

Comment: Maybe regex them out by id: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138710/parse-public-keys-from-txt-file-by-php

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Then the key is not taken at all.

Comment: openssl_verify param for `$ecdsa_keys` can be a string (extracted key) or resource (from openssl_pkey_get_public). so you could remove the openssl_pkey_get_public line entirely.

Comment: ok, thx. I try.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone nope. If I try use as public key the string 'some_ecdsa_key', I get a warning message 'Warning: openssl_verify(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a public key in... '

Answer (score 0):

@Lawrence Cherone answer work for me.
[Parse public keys from .txt file by php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138710/parse-public-keys-from-txt-file-by-php)

my code:

```
$ecdsa_keys = file_get_contents(PATH . '/ecdsa_keys.txt');
$ecdsa_key_id = 'KEY_FROM_URL';

function getKeyById($id, $ecdsa_keys){
    if(preg_match("~KEY_ID: $id\s+STATUS: VALID\s+(-{5}BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-{5}.+?-{5}END PUBLIC KEY-{5})~s", $ecdsa_keys, $match)){
        $result = $match[1];
        return $result;
    }
    return null;
}

if(($ecdsa_key = getKeyById($ecdsa_key_id, $ecdsa_keys)) !== null){
    echo "<pre>".$ecdsa_key."</pre>";
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

thx for help